# Movie with humans battling aliens piloting giant animalistic, water-walking robots or sea warships

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I have memories of watching it a few years ago (I was a kid then) in the early 2000s probably; before 2010 I think. It was a movie with giant robots, and the enemies were aliens piloting what I remember as giant, more animalistic robots. I remember those animalistic ones running on water. The aliens themselves were a little taller than humans but mostly humanoid. I remember what the aliens look like a bit; most of the movie they were clad in some kind of armor, but the scene I mentioned showed one's face, if I remember well, grey skin, vividly green eyes, a beard made of some kind of quills, bald.

I have this one scene that stayed crystal clear in my memories. The heroes had captured an injured alien, and other aliens attack to, in the end, just retrieve the injured one, leaving with this one without attacking further this time.

I also remember the aliens going through a city in some machine (I'm actually not sure this one was piloted though) and destroying anything it perceived as a threat, from cars to security cameras.

My memories are coming from years ago, so I might be wrong in a bunch of things there, but this one scene, I can assure is correct. This might remind a bit of *Pacific Rim*, but it isn't. (It's watching *Pacific Rim* that reminded me of this movie.) It doesn't seem to show up on any giant robot movie list on internet, weirdly, so I hope you can help me.

And now I'm starting to wonder if there was really robots on the heroes' side. Maybe it was warships (sea ones, not spaceships). As I said it was some time ago and I was young, so bad memories are likely.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the description of the face of the aliens, this would seem to be the movie [*Battleship*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(film)) from 2012.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1440129/):

> An international fleet of naval warships encounters an alien armada while on a Naval war games exercise and faces the biggest threat mankind has ever faced. An intense battle is fought on sea, land and air. If they lose, the world could face a major extinction event and an alien invasion. Will humans win this alien war, what are the aliens doing here, and what do they want?

This clip shows a group of soldiers removing the helmet of an armor wearing, humanoid alien, who has a "quill" like "beard", grey skin, and vivid green eyes.

Comment: Yes ! That's the movie !

Comment: So it really was boats and not robots, I remembered wrong.

Comment: If you have the movie then keep watching after all the closing credits, there's a bonus scene set in Scotland

Comment: @DannyMcG I haven’t seen it, from what I understand it’s unlikely someone would watch it to the end, never mind stick around for the credits too.